# Docusaurus v2 - Search bar does not show up in Navbar

Tags: docusaurus

Default Search bar does not show up in the header nav on a new site built using Docusaurus V2

[image]

but `/search` shows the search page:

[image]

Steps I followed:

1. Created a new site using command `npx @docusaurus/init@latest init mysite classic`.
2. Per documentation, classic should include Search https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/@docusaurus/theme-search-algolia ?
3. Added this to `docusaurus.config.js`

   ```
   themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
     items: [
       {
         type: 'search',
         position: 'right',
       },
    ...
    ...
   ```

The documentation here https://docusaurus.io/docs/search does not mention clearly how to the default search bar shows up. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to install `@docusaurus/theme-search-algolia`  (https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/@docusaurus/theme-search-algolia). I suppose that you need to connect Algolia (https://docusaurus.io/docs/search#connecting-algolia) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```sh
$ npm install --save @docusaurus/theme-search-algolia
```

Reference to: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/4975